# tkウィジェットのオプションの値をモニタしたい

Tags: tk, ウィジェット

同僚に勉強会の一部として、こんなtcl/tk windowを作りたい。

```
 _________________________________________
|                  |   ________________   |
| -bg: 0x112233    |  |_button_example_|  |
| -height: 5       |                      |
| -justify: center |  O radio example     |
| -padx: 2         |                      |
| ......           |                      |
|__________________|______________________|
```

右は複数のtkウィジェットがあり、左はそのウィジェットのオプションと現在の値を示しています。

マウスがあるウィジェットの上に置いた時、またはクリックした時、左にそのウィジェットのすべてのオプションをモニタできます。（リアルタイム値をディスプレイします）

global変数（例えば、`set kk 123`の`kk`）をモニタするには、

```
label .label1 -textvariable kk
```

で十分だと分かりますが、ウィジェットオプションの値をモニタするにはどうやっていいのですか。

Comment: この記事 [Is it possible to get widget settings in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3221908/9014308) のこちらの[回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32202843/9014308) を試してみては？ `keys()`で名前を取得して、`cget()`で値を取得するようです。

Comment: @kunif 今オリジナルtcl/tkを使用中です。その回答とだいたい同じで、`<widget> configure`や`<widget> cget`でその<widget>のすべてのオプションのリストおよび値を取得できます。しかし、ある時点で前のコマンドを実行して、ディスプレイを手動で更新必要があります。意図したのは`label .label1 -textvariable kk`のように、目標を指定し、tkが自動モニタ/更新です。

Comment: `mouse`の何かの`event`や何か`widget`の`after`ルーチンで、その時点でのマウスポジションと対応する`widget`を算出して、対象に変化があったら取得・表示し直す、とかが考えられます。

Comment: @kunif Never used that. I'll give it a try. Thx.

Comment: ちなみにこんな記事が参考になるかも。[Tkinter - On which widget is mouse pointer currently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46304077/9014308), [Display message when hovering over something with mouse cursor in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20399243/9014308)